# NestJs can't inject services into authguard

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, auth-guard

As the title of the post says, I can't inject service in the following authguard class, I get an error each time I try to, the error happens in the JwtAccessTokenGuard where I try to inject the JwtTokenService to access some of the class method however it does not woks as expected :

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtAccessTokenGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    @Inject(JwtTokenService) private readonly jwtTokenService: JwtTokenService,
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const token = this.extractTokenFromHeader(request);
    if (!token) throw new UnauthorizedException();
    try {
      return true;
    } catch {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
  }

  private extractTokenFromHeader(request: Request): string | undefined {
    const [type, token] = request.headers.authorization?.split(' ') ?? [];
    return type === 'Bearer' ? token : undefined;
  }
}
```

I already added global guard in app module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
    PrismaModule,
    BcryptModule,
    JwtTokenModule,
    LibModule,
    TwoFaModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: JwtAccessTokenGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is the User Module :

```
@Module({
  controllers: [UserController, JwtTokenModule],
  providers: [UserService, PrismaService],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

and here is the Jwt Module :

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtTokenService } from './jwtToken.service';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Module({
  imports: [JwtModule],
  providers: [JwtTokenService],
  exports: [JwtTokenService],
})
export class JwtTokenModule {}
```

and this is the error returned by nestjs:

```
[Nest] 79549  - 09/28/2023, 12:35:42 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtAccessTokenGuard (?). Please make sure that the argument JwtTokenService at index [0] is available in the UserModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is UserModule a valid NestJS module?
- If JwtTokenService is a provider, is it part of the current UserModule?
- If JwtTokenService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UserModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing JwtTokenService */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtAccessTokenGuard (?). Please make sure that the argument JwtTokenService at index [0] is available in the UserModule context.
```

Comment: why do you have that `@Inject(JwtTokenService)` (although it should work)? does it works without `@Inject()`?

Comment: What does the import of `JwtTokenService` look like in the `AuthGuard`?

Comment: I figured out what was the problem, it was because I imported some module as controller, in other module !